# calling shell_exec in a php file goes to infinite loop

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, cron

After asking many to help, even the support from where I'm hosting my website none of them could help me. So here I am trying my last bullet.

All I'm trying to do is to run this cron.php script from my browser:

```
<?php
    $output = shell_exec('bash startup.sh');
    die();
?>
```

This is startup.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

# Start tracker session
screen -S Track -d -m bash public-tracker
echo "Started tracker session!"
```

And this is public-tracker file

```
#!/bin/sh

`which php` ../../public-track.php something | tee -a tracker.log
```

And public-track.php is simply:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World";
?>
```

When I run cron.php, I getting data to tracker.log in a very fast way until I rename cron.php to something else. Then it will stop.

The data I'm infinitely receiving to tracker.log is something like that:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.30
Content-type: text/html

X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.30
Content-type: text/html

X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.30
Content-type: text/html

X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.30
Content-type: text/html

X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.30
Content-type: text/html

X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.30
Content-type: text/html
```

These lines keep spamming to tracker.log until I rename cron.php to something else.

What may be causing this issue ? 
Thanks

Comment: What is `public-track.php` doing? What does `which php` return?

Comment: public-track.php is a simple echo "hello world". And `which php` is used to run the php script, I could replace it by php

Comment: If you run `startup.sh` manually does it work correctly or do this looping? And I meant what does `which php` return *exactly*? What does it **actually** output for you?

Comment: Yes if I run "bash startup.sh" from the SSH it works perfectly.
which php doesnt return anything, it's stuck like that: https://i.gyazo.com/d350aa06d5ef7c1fa921ab93556ea23f.png

Comment: When this loops do you have multiple `screen` sessions running on your machine? Or just one? Do you have multiple `<whatever which php returns> public-track.php` processes running? Do you ever see the `Hello World` output?

Comment: I didn't say `\`which php\``. I said `which php`. With the backticks you ran the output and php is not waiting for input.

Comment: which php returns: /usr/local/bin/php.
And even if I had no other screens running, I still get the infinite loop, "Hello World" doesn't appear in the output file tracker.log.

Comment: You misunderstood my question. When it loops do you have multiple screen sessions? Is each copy of the output coming from a new screen session or from something else. The question is **where** is the looping/etc. happening. Are you sure this isn't just the browser (or many browsers) hammering on `cron.php`?

Comment: @EtanReisner This is the scenario, I go using my browser to the url location of cron.php, the page stops loading within seconds of launching it. The circle icon next to the tab in the browser stops turning.

Comment: @EtanReisner I close the tab, and even the browser. tracker.log starts getting spammed with data. In my SSH this is ps -x and top commands before I launch the cron.php: https://i.gyazo.com/c679ddc6892087557c021624cd9f68e2.png & https://i.gyazo.com/a017c4e0b8b906c2d382b0218881f477.png  and this is ps -x and top commands AFTER I run the cron.php https://i.gyazo.com/37209c15fb0cb6129aae1ed5c5447b97.png & https://i.gyazo.com/8c1fcabbab563d1ba2cc4f1ffcc60673.gif

Comment: I would remove the `screen` from `startup.sh` and execute `bash public-tracker` directly.  You won't have a `tty` in a `cron` job, so the use of `screen` bothers me, I don't know if it needs a terminal or not.  Also check all of your paths to the various scripts that you're calling.  If the code runs in a different directory, it might not be able to find the commands.